# Enviar datos a otra pagina sin ponerlas en el enlace

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo la siguiente lista de cursos que se genera de forma dinámica:

```
<table style="border: white 5px solid;">
  <tr>
    <th style="background-color: #ed7d31; color: #ffffff; width: 360px;">Nombre</th>
    <th style="background-color: #ed7d31; color: #ffffff; width: 120px;">Fecha inicio</th>
    <th style="background-color: #ed7d31; color: #ffffff; width: 120px;">Fecha fin</th>
    <th style="background-color: #ed7d31; color: #ffffff; width: 120px;">Estado</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="fila-2005">
    <td style="background-color: #f8cbad;">Control de Contratos</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #f8cbad;">2020-08-28</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #f8cbad;">2020-12-30</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #f8cbad;"><a href='index.php/curso-visible'>Visible</a></td>
  </tr>
    <tr id="fila-2006">
    <td style="background-color: #f8cbad;">Gantt y Curva S para Ingeniería de Mantenimiento</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #f8cbad;">2020-08-01</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #f8cbad;">2020-12-31</td>
    <td style="text-align: center; background-color: #f8cbad;"><a href='index.php/curso-visible'>Visible</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Mediante el enlace "Visible", necesito enviar datos ("id") a otra pagina sin modificar la URL del href ("index.php/curso-visible"). Encontré el siguiente código de javascript que podría servir:

```
$(function() {
      $('#btn_save').on('click', function() {
          $.post('index.php/curso-visible', {
              "idcurso": id
            },function(data) {
              console.log('procesamiento finalizado', data);
          });
      })
})
```

Pero este código sirve para un botón y no sirve para que la variable "id" cambie de acuerdo al enlace seleccionado. Es decir, en una fila la id es "fila-2005" y en otra "fila-2006".
Para mi javascript es el lenguaje mas feo que puede haber y necesito su ayuda.
Muchas gracias por su ayuda

Comment: El problema no es Javascript, el problema es lograr usarlo de forma adecuada. El código que dices que encontraste y que sirve para un botón, es de JQuery, una librería escrita sobre Javascript. Por lo que entiemdo en tu pregunta, deseas evitar que al hacer clic sobre los enlaces, la página navegue hacia la dirección proporcionada en el atributo `href` del mismo. ¿Es correcto?

Comment: A la pregunta le falta mayor información. 
Exactamente ¿que es lo que quiere hacer?
¿Donde se encuentra el boton `#btn_save`?

Comment: Hola @MauricioContreras. No es correcto. Creo que hice mal la pregunta. En la lista que publique hay varios enlaces con el mismo href, pero deben enviar diferentes datos (id). No puedo anexar esos datos en la URL. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Hola @OscarCely. En la lista que publique hay varios enlaces con el mismo href, pero deben enviar diferentes datos (id). No puedo anexar esos datos en la URL. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Creo entender lo que quiere es hacer que cada link tenga el id del curso y lo envie mediante una peticion POST al backend de PHP usando AJAX si asi es, pues ocultar el id no es posible realmente, ya esas peticiones se hacen via JavaScript, y pues estos scripts se cargan en el buscador y por lo tanto serán visibles para el navegador y el usuario.

Si es asi y desea implementarlo de este modo, quisiera saber si los datos de la tabla los está poniendo manualmente, o programaticamente con PHP?

Comment: Hola @OscarCely. Como dices, si quiero enviar el id del curso pero que no se vea en la URL del navegador, solo en esa parte. Si la solución es enviarlo por Ajax, a mi me parece bien. La tabla se genera programaticamente con PHP.

Answer (score 0):

> Necesito enviar datos a otra pagina sin modificar la URL del href.
> Encontré el siguiente código de javascript que podría servir

si entendí bien, lo que queres es que tu "boton" no sea un `<a></a>` con estilos de botón, para eso es correcto el código que encontraste, es **ajax** desde **jquery** es muy eficiente si queres conseguir resultados inmediatos, pero...

- tenes que entender como enviarlo a la tecnología que estés usando (ya que no especificaste si estas usando C# en el backend, o nodejs o php). y si estas pensando en **JSON** te recomiendo que investigues como utilizar **REST**
- falta información, pero tenes que ir pensando que necesitas "backend" algún lenguaje que corra en lado del servidor y una base de datos, todos los podes investigar y elegir a gusto, por la forma en la que escribiste los detalles necesitan pasar primero por este punto(lo que recién comente) para poder llevar datos de una vista a la otra.
  o como muy loco para prescindir de eso, utiliza localstorage del navegador, pero eso como máximo es de practica, simulación.

Estos links puede que te sirvan:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qk2cqRtWkDo
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9W0aW78o14

> Pero este código sirve para un botón y no sirve para que la variable
> "idcurso" cambie de acuerdo al enlace seleccionado. Para mi javascript
> es el lenguaje mas feo que puede haber y necesito su ayuda.

1. Muy mala practica cambiarle el id a cualquier elemento.
2. te recomendó que uses algún atributo propio para manejar dicho valor que estés recibiendo, que necesites que vaya mutando , ej: data-valor = "0" -> cambia a "1"
3. Javascript para empezar, y para trabajar es muy cómodo, tiene demasiado trabajo por detrás, pero el problema de no ser tipado te puede desilusionar, de ser así, usa typescript. ya que es una versión tipada de javascript. ya que cuando investigues veras, que te gusta y vas a encontrarte con Nodejs(Javascript del servidor). como una opción.

Comment: Hola @GiantLaxus. Siento no haberme explicado bien. No quiero usar un botón. En la lista que publique hay varios enlaces con el mismo href, pero deben enviar diferentes datos (id="fila-2005"). No puedo anexar esos datos en la URL. El código Javascript  que puse solo es una pista para resolver mi problema.  En cuanto a la tecnología que estoy usando, estoy tratando de crear contenido dentro del Front End de Joomla. Osea ya crear una pagina que envié datos a otra dentro de este ambiente.  Modifique mi pregunta para que sea mas clara.

Answer (score 0):

Siendo asi entonces lo que yo recomendaria hacer es lo siguiente:

1. Incluir Jquery al proyecto (si no esta incluido) ya que me parece facilita las ejecuciones de AJAX
2. Al traer los cursos de la base de datos, estos llegaran en un array que va a ser iterable y que deduzco los esta manejando en la vista con un `foreach`. Y que tambien esta trayendo el id de cada curso.
3. La verdad no tengo idea si va a eliminar ese campo al momento de clickear en visible o no pero el caso es lo mas recomendable es que a lo que vaya a cambiar le ponga el id del curso. Si por ejemplo va a cambiar toda la fila completa, entonces si es necesario poner el `<tr id="fila-2005">`, pero si solo va a cambiar el texto que dice visible y poner otro, hay que poner el id en el ultimo `td`
4. En el ultimo `td` donde va el link de *visible* no poner URL en `href` porque la idea no es recargar una nueva pagina, en vez de eso pone un `#` asi:
5. Para ejecutar el llamado de AJAX vamos a crear una funcion de JS ya sea dentro de la pagina o dentro del archivo .js que tenga. Esta funcion que llamare *ajax* recibe un argumento que será el id del curso y va asi:

```
<script>
        function ajax(id) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'text',
                url: 'index.php/curso-visible',
                data: {
                    id : id
                },
                error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);

                },
                success: function (res) {
                    document.getElementById("fila-"+id).innerHTML = res;
                },
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Donde `dataType` es el tipo de dato esperado que se va a devolver JSON, or XML, HTML, text, etc.
En `success` se indica que se va a hacer con el valor retornado de la pagina visitada por ajax.
6. En el link seria llamar la funcion cuando se de click al link `<td style="text-align: center; background-color: #f8cbad;"><a href='#' onclick="ajax(<?php echo $curso["id"]?>)">visible</a></td>`
7. A la nueva pagina llegara la variable enviada por post y alla ya hace lo que requiera con la bd y demas